# RMSE calculations

Tags: stationarity, rms

I have a uni-variate regression model in which both dependent and independent variables are non-stationary. They turn stationary upon first-differencing. I want to compare the original form of the model (with stationarity) with the first-differenced form. I have the following questions in this regard:

1) Can the predictive power measures such as RMSE be relied upon if the model has stationarity issues?

2) For first-differenced model, for comparison, should I compute RMSE based on $Y$ residuals or $\Delta Y$ residuals?

Comment: 1) why shouldn't it? It is just an error measure. 2) Are you predicting $Y$ or $\Delta Y$? Simply: you measure error of what you are going to predict.

Comment: 2) I am predicting $Y$, but if I measure errors of $Y$ for RMSE calculation, it disproportionately depends on the first value of $Y$ (A large deviation dies out slowly over the series, affecting RMSE). That's why I was wondering if there is any best practice in this context.